# IPad modal form size problems when rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am presenting a UINavigationController+UICollectionViewController as a form on iPad, and would like it to have explicit sizes on landscape and portrait orientations. For some reason my approach below fails to deliver consistent results after rotation. It seems to work for the initial presentation on both orientations, and when rotating from landscape to portrait. Rotating from portrait to landscape breaks it.

Please note I am targeting iOS 10+ so many of the existing advice available do not apply anymore.

```
@implementation FormCVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...

    [self setupFrame];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id _Nonnull context) {
        [self setupFrame];
    } completion:^(id _Nonnull context) {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        [layout invalidateLayout];
    }];
}

- (void)setupFrame {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");

        self.preferredContentSize  = CGSizeMake(VIEW_PORTRAIT_WIDTH, VIEW_PORTRAIT_HEIGHT);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");

        self.preferredContentSize  = CGSizeMake(VIEW_LANDSCAPE_WIDTH, VIEW_LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT);
    }

    [self.navigationController.presentationController.containerView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.navigationController.presentationController.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually as simple as adding `self.navigationController.preferredContentSize = ...`

after each

`self.preferredContentSize = ...`